# How to select a pixel from an image and reduce the opacity of that pixel in Android programming

Tags: java, android, pixel, opacity

I want to select a pixel from an image that is displayed in the Image View and then change the opacity of the same pixel without changing the opacity of the rest of the image pixels.
For example, I select a point with position x = 50 and y = 70, and I just want the opacity to change in this point and not change the opacity elsewhere.How can I do that?

Comment: Is your image a bitmap?

Comment: Yes, my image is a bitmap

Comment: This is the bitmap code of my program

Comment: Your bitmap probably won't be mutable, that's the problem. See my answer.

Comment: Bitmap bitmap =((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
 int pixel = bitmap .getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());

Comment: What should I do if I want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I managed to do:

```java
// Decode the bitmap resource and make sure it's mutable.
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inMutable = true;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.black, opts);

imv.setImageBitmap(bm);

imv.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        // Get the color of the touched pixel and change only the alpha component.
        int color = bm.getPixel(x, y);
        int alpha = color >>> 24;
        alpha /= 2;  // Alpha will be divided by two in the final color.
        color = color & 0xFFFFFF | alpha << 24;

        // Change the pixel color on the bitmap and update the ImageView.
        bm.setPixel(x, y, color);
        imv.setImageBitmap(bm);
        imv.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

It's a little more than what you asked but I needed to test it. When you click on the ImageView, the opacity (alpha) of the pixel you clicked on is halved.

That's actually barely perceptible on most phones because the screen has a very high density.

Comment: @abbas8080salahi Show me the stacktrace, on pastebin maybe.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with canvas?

Comment: Probably but I would need more details

Comment: The number of stacktrace characters is large and cannot be displayed through comments

Comment: 05-16 23:01:32.891 2238-2238/com.example.myapplicationop E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
05-16 23:01:32.891 2238-2238/com.example.myapplicationop E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-16 23:01:32.895 2238-2238/com.example.myapplicationop E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()

Comment: at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1403)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1352)
        at com.example.myapplicationop.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9290)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)

Comment: at at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)

Comment: at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)

Comment: at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)

Comment: at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)

Comment: at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-16 23:01:37.157 2238-2238/com.example.myapplicationop I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2238 SIG: 9

Comment: You know I suggested you use pastebin for a reason... Anyway, you should check that the event's x and y fit the bitmap bounds. You can't change a pixel at x=-1 y=-1 for example.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: Make sure the touch is within bitmap bounds.

Comment: How to do it in the canvas?